# Python PyQt4 invalid syntax

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have been trying out some pieces of codes from [this kyui project](http://code.google.com/p/kyui/). And I have run into this following code for ribbon.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class KyRibbonBar(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent : QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMovable(False)
        self.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.setElideMode(Qt.ElideNone)
        self.setUsesScrollButtons(False)
        self.__menuWidget = None

    def menuWidget(self) -> QWidget:
        return self.__menuWidget

    def setMenuWidget(self, widget : QWidget = None) -> None:
        self.setCornerWidget(widget, Qt.TopLeftCorner)

    def addRibbonTab(self, text : str, icon : QIcon = None) -> QToolBar:
        index = self.addTab(QToolBar(text, self), text)
        if icon:
            assert isinstance(icon, QIcon)
            self.setTabIcon(index, icon)

    def setTabText(self, index : int = 0, text : str = None) -> None:
        assert isinstance(text, str)
        super().setTabText(index)
        self.widget(index).setWindowTitle(text)
```

However, when i run the code itself, it actually give me error message saying that "invalid syntax" and highlighting the `:` in `def __init__(self, parent : QWidget = None):`

what are these `:` and `->` symbols do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's function annotations introduced in Python 3.0.

According to [PEP 3107 -- Function Annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/):

> Function annotations, both for parameters and return values, are
>   completely optional.
>
> Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating
>   arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at
>   compile-time.
>
> By itself, Python does not attach any particular meaning or
>   significance to annotations. Left to its own, Python simply makes
>   these expressions available as described in [Accessing Function
>   Annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#accessing-function-annotations) below.
>
> The only way that annotations take on meaning is when they are
>   interpreted by third-party libraries. These annotation consumers can
>   do anything they want with a function's annotations.

You cannot use this syntax in Python 2.x.

Comment: Which means unless I am using python 3, I can't use that piece of code?

Comment: @ChrisAung, You're right. If you want to use that code in Python 2.x, remove annotations.

Comment: @ChrisAung: Just remove everything from (and **including**) the colon up until (but **not** including) the equals and it should work the same. Eg, change the offending line to read `def __init__(self, parent = None):` and similarly for other instances of the function annotations.